# Google Authentication (popup)

Tags: java, javascript, authentication, jsf

I've made a popup myself to authenticate a google account. The problem is, when I log into any google account, it closes the popup window and does not refresh the webpage that has the link to open the popup. Is there a solution already implemented that works? Or I really need to implement one myself?

If is there any other way to do it, please let me know. I'm kind of desperate.

Opening the pop up:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/home/convite/conviteGmail.jsf" onclick="showPopup(this.href);return(false);" >Gmail</a>
```

The pop up itself:

```
<h:outputLabel for="login" styleClass="email_convite">Login: </h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="login" value="#{conviteGmailBean.login}" />
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel for="password" styleClass="email_convite">Password: </h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{conviteGmailBean.password}" />
            </div>
                <h:outputText value="#{conviteGmailBean.mensagemErro}" rendered="#{conviteGmailBean.erro}"/>
```

Closing the pop up:

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{conviteGmailBean.logarGmail}" oncomplete="javascript:window.close()"  rendered="#{!conviteGmailBean.autenticado}" value="Login" reRender="convidarAmigosForm" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the closing pop up part to:

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{conviteGmailBean.logarGmail}" oncomplete="javascript:window.opener.parent.document.location.href='#{request.contextPath}/home/convite/convite.jsf';javascript:window.close()" rendered="#{!conviteGmailBean.autenticado}" value="Login" reRender="convidarAmigosForm" />
```

Source:

> http://www.computing.net/answers/webdevel/reload-other-page-from-popup-window/1762.html